# Nice code template for windows service

Tags: windows-services

Any links to a good template for a windows service?  (looking for C# code)

Something that has the basic functionality that I could extend.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little clear what you are looking for.  The **Windows Service** project type in Visual Studio creates a project with the templates you need to get going with a basic windows service.

You can also look at [this article](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service) from C# Online.  It goes over a few ideas and has a few parts to the article.  *(Note; the page seems to loads a little slow so be patient)*

Answer (score 1):

I use VS2005 and I like to start with the basic template.

Modify the Service class to this

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        //better is to read from settings or config file
        private readonly Double _interval = (new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds;
        private Timer m_Timer;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            m_Timer = new Timer();
            m_Timer.BeginInit();
            m_Timer.AutoReset = false;
            m_Timer.Enabled = true;
            m_Timer.Interval = 1000.0;
            m_Timer.Elapsed += m_Timer_Elapsed;
            m_Timer.EndInit();
        }

        private void m_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO WORK WORK WORK
            RestartTimer();
        }

        private void RestartTimer()
        {
            m_Timer.Interval = _interval;
            m_Timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Stop();
            base.OnStop();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            m_Timer.Start();
        }

        public new void Stop()
        {
            m_Timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Install using InstallUtil.exe, after you have added an installer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(VS.80).aspx

Keep the Init function small and fast, otherwise your service will not start with an error that the service did not respond in a timely fashion

Hope this helps